# Unmanaged c++ DLL in C#... WINAPI and Pointers

Tags: c#, c++, pointers, pinvoke, dllimport

I've been asked to intergrate webcam ZoneTrigger in my project. The SDK provided in the site is C++ also the sample. I've been able to get few functions to work. the place i've been stuck is a function where callback is done. 
Code in sample c++ the callback function

```
ZT_SetCallbackProc(ZoneTriggerCallbackProc);
```

// in header file

```
typedef int (WINAPI *f_ZT_SetCallbackProc) (void *proc);
/*
Sets up the callback function for your application.
The proc should be declared like this:

int WINAPI ZoneTriggerCallbackProc(int MessageType, ZT_TRIG_STRUCT *trigInfo);

MessageType may be one of the following:
0:  Zone Trigger sends a trig. The trigInfo contains data about the hot spots that generated the trig.
1:  Zone Trigger has started and is notifying us that it is ready. This only occurs when Zone Trigger starts after the interface DLL is loaded.
2:  Zone Trigger is shutting down. You application may need to know this. If Zone Trigger is started again, your application will get message 1.
3:  Zone Trigger's Hot spot scheme has changed (a Hot Spot was added or deleted)
*/
```

my c# code:

```
[DllImport("ZTcom.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr ZT_SetCallbackProc(int ZoneTriggerCallbackProc);

 private unsafe int ZoneTriggerCallbackProc(int MessageType, ref ZT_TRIG_STRUCT trigInfo)
    {
        switch (MessageType)
        {

            case 0:     //Trig from a Zone Trigger hot spot
                // string s1 = new string(trigInfo.SpotName);
                MessageBox.Show("Got a trig from spot" + trigInfo.SpotIndex.ToString()+ s1 );
                break;

            case 1:     //Zone Trigger has started and is notifying us that it is ready
                MessageBox.Show("Zone Trigger issued a ready notification.\r\n");
                break;

            case 2:     //Zone Trigger is shutting down
                MessageBox.Show("Zone Trigger has left the building.\r\n");
                break;

            case 3:     //Hot spot scheme updated, you might want yo re-enumerate the hot spots
                MessageBox.Show("Zone Trigger's hot spots have been updated.\r\n");
                break;


        }
        return 0;
    }
```

i've reached so far... but i dont understand how to call the ZT_SetCallbackProc function?

```
 IntPtr tg = IntPtr.Zero;
            tg = ZT_SetCallbackProc(ZoneTriggerCallbackProc);
```

this gives error that ZoneTriggerCallbackProc is a method group. plz help... thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you need to declare a delegate, see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468\(v=VS.71\).aspx#pinvoke_registeringcallback) and your function probably also needs to be `static`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Daniel's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7318170/unmanaged-c-dll-in-c-winapi-and-pointers/7319300#7319300) has the simple and quick route. If you don't want to run into problems (as the delegate can get collected by the GC resulting in an AccessViolationException) you will need to do the following.

The type/pinvoke declarations from Daniel (for completeness):

```
// int WINAPI ZoneTriggerCallbackProc(int MessageType, ZT_TRIG_STRUCT *trigInfo);  
delegate int ZoneTriggerCallbackProc(int messageType, ref ZT_TRIG_STRUCT trigInfo); 
[DllImport("ZTcom.dll")]   
private static extern IntPtr ZT_SetCallbackProc(ZoneTriggerCallbackProc callbackProc);
```

In your wrapper class, hold a reference to the delegate, so that the GC doesn't collect the delegate while the callback is set.

```
public class ZoneTrigger : CriticalFinalizerObject
{
  private ZoneTriggerCallbackProc _zoneTriggerCallback;
  private IntPtr _zoneTriggerCallbackCookie;

  public ZoneTrigger()
  {
    _zoneTriggerCallback = ZoneTriggerCallback;
    // Why not just do it here?
    _zoneTriggerCallbackCookie = NativeMethods.ZT_SetCallbackProc(_zoneTriggerCallback);
    if (_zoneTriggerCallbackCookie == IntPtr.Zero)
       throw new Exception("Failed to set callback");
  }

   private unsafe int ZoneTriggerCallback(int MessageType, ref ZT_TRIG_STRUCT trigInfo)
   {
     // ...
   }

  ~ZoneTrigger()
  {
     var oldCookie = Interlocked.Exchange(ref _zoneTriggerCallback, IntPtr.Zero);
     if (oldCookie != IntPtr.Zero)
       ZT_ClearCallbackProc(oldCookie);
  }
}
```

**NB:** Please accept Daniel's answer, this is more of an addition to it.

Comment: Thank you very much... this worked .... i wud accept Daniel's answer but i'd still b lost if u hadnt given the above explanation... thank you very much.....

Answer (score 2):

The callback function is a method. So you need to pass a method to it. In C# you get that by defining a delegate:

```
// int WINAPI ZoneTriggerCallbackProc(int MessageType, ZT_TRIG_STRUCT *trigInfo); 
delegate int ZoneTriggerCallbackProc(int messageType, ref ZT_TRIG_STRUCT trigInfo);

[DllImport("ZTcom.dll")] 
private static extern IntPtr ZT_SetCallbackProc(ZoneTriggerCallbackProc callbackProc);
```

Answer (score 0):

Call the function as follows....

```
 ZT_TRIG_STRUCT triginfo = new ZT_TRIG_STRUCT();
 IntPtr tg = IntPtr.Zero;
        tg = ZT_SetCallbackProc(ZoneTriggerCallbackProc(0,triginfo));
```